# Make Value in Dropdownlist not selectable

Tags: jquery

I've created a dropdownlist that looks somewhat like this :

```
Item1
     Item2
     Item3
Item4
     Item5
     Item6
     Item7
```

I would like to make Item1 and Item4 as non selectable items. Is this possible with Jquery? 

LaterEdit:
I should be able to select item1 and item4 (events) through my class called fooheader 
and rest of the selectable items are called by fooDetails class.

At the moment my temporary fix makes the next value from the Dll the selected value , but I'm looking for a more elegant solution to the issue

Comment: what dropdownlist is used

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/ ?

Comment: You need `<optgroup>`... http://jsfiddle.net/Y8pyC/

Comment: @limelights I knew this would come as a comment. I've added as a later edit . Frankly , I did not find a single piece of documentation regarding readonly values for dropdownlist

Comment: Thanks Archer thats what i was looking for . Please add it as an answer

Comment: Glad to help mate - answer added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `<optgroup>`...

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Item 1">
    <option>Item 2</option>
    <option>Item 3</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Item 4">
    <option>Item 5</option>
    <option>Item 6</option>
    <option>Item 7</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Here's a jsFiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/DKLwv/

If you don't want them nested, do it like this...

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Item 1"></optgroup>
  <option>Item 2</option>
  <option>Item 3</option>
  <optgroup label="Item 4"></optgroup>
  <option>Item 5</option>
  <option>Item 6</option>
  <option>Item 7</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <select>
<option value="" disabled>---------------------</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Emm .. I've finnaly finnished this part .. I had some problems with modifying my DDL placing the  option to several fields within my dropdown list . 
This is my solution, maybe it helps someone else ( and gets me some extra upvotes in the process :P )

```
 var $groups = $("#ddlId").filter(function () {
        return $(this).css('color') == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'; // your condition of finding the optgroup elements 
    });
    $groups.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.nextUntil($groups).wrapAll($("<optgroup>", {
            label: $this.text()
        })).end().remove();
    });
```